# populating request data in two different JSP's

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

I have an jsp that is populated by a servlet during initialization . I now need to populate another jsp that is called from the first jsp with information that I get in the request object . I have tried the following methods

1) populate a hidden div in jsp 1 with the info I need and try to retrieve that info in jsp 2 using javascript using  `document.getElementById(#theDivID).value` but the value is undefined .

2) tried accessing the request object in jsp 2 but it does not exist in this scope .

I would be grateful if someone could explain to me how I could do this .

Thanks

Comment: Maybe post the relevant parts of your existing JSP code? Also what do you mean by "is called from the first JSP"? Is it included on the server-side or is it a separate request issued by the user after interacting with the page generated by the first JSP?

Answer (score 0):

```
1) populate a hidden div in jsp 1 with the info I need and try to retrieve that info in jsp 2 using javascript using  document.getElementById(#theDivID).value but the value is undefined .

2) tried accessing the request object in jsp 2 but it does not exist in this scope .
```

**This 2 things wont work because you have set the value in the request scope . it will be available only for the particular request**

You could do either of the below options,

1. Could set the value in the `Session` and access it through out application
2. Or redirect the request from the `jsp1` to servlet again and send the response back to `jsp2`

**NOTE**

You can also pass the value from the jsp1 using the query string as,

```
<a href="second.jsp?value=${value}">second</a>
```

Hope this helps !!